# How do you dynamically translate database field names?

Tags: php, database, design-patterns, architecture, application-design

All,

What is the proper way to translate a database field name, to something humanly readable?

Lets say you have a table structured like this:

```
model_no | lift_height_ft | net_weight_lbs | min_headroom
12345           24               200              12
67891           36               400              24
```

But you want it to translate those field names when displaying to:

```
Model # | Lifting Height (ft) | Net Weight (lbs) | Minimum Headroom
12345           24                  200                  12
67891           36                  400                  24
```

I was thinking you would store the translated titles in a separate table to perform lookups when displaying (ex. echo translate_title("model_no") -> "Model #"), but I wanted a second opinion.

Thanks!

Comment: Any requirement for multi-language support?

Answer (score 2):

Aliases:

```
SELECT model_no AS 'Model #', lifting_height_ft AS 'Lifting Height (ft)', etc...
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^---the alias
```

Comment: I like that too, but it requires me to hard-code those titles into the code. Which I'm not certain is a good or bad thing.

Comment: then you're stuck doing it client-side, in which case you can use any translation mechanism you want.